# How to reference a method of an element of an enum in java

Tags: java, enums, javadoc

Given an enum class `E` with elements `A` and `B` and method `m`,
how to reference E.A.m in javadoc?
This problem occurs if one has to mention properties of `m` specific for `A`.
In particular, if `E.m` is overwritten for `A` or if `E.m` is abstract
and each element provides its own implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'properties of m specific for A'? A is just an instance of class m so, by definition, has the same fields as every other instance. Do you mean a method that is specific to just one instance? You might need to give a practical example to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is currently **impossible** in Java, and for a very specific reason. In short, `A` and `B` in your example are both an `instance`, and Java does not allow JavaDoc for instances.

An `enum` in Java is really meant to be syntactic sugar (plus some ***VERY POWERFUL*** functionality) for a very common design pattern for versions of Java earlier than 1.5.

The common design pattern was when we wanted to have a `class` with a very *restricted* and *limited* number of `instances`. Most classes allow you to make as many `instances` of them as memory allows. But an ***enumerated*** type has a known, limited (,and typically small) number of `instances`.

And the most important word here is `instance`. Consider the following code.

```java
   public enum E
   {
   
      A,
      B,
      ;
      
   }
```

In the above example, `E` is a class, specifically, an `enum` class. ***However, A and B are merely `INSTANCES` of `E`***. They are not subclasses. They are not any sort of type as far as Java is aware. They are nothing more than if you said the following.

```java
public class E
{

    public static final A = new E();
    public static final B = new E();

    //whatever other functionality enums provide for you out of the box

}
```

That is important, because in Java, javadoc is only ever documented for ***types/fields/etc***, but not for ***anonymous instances of types***. Think about it. To make `m` have a different functionality, you must make an anonymous class for `E`, and then override the implementation fo `::m` for each instance.

So this is allowed and will show up on JavaDoc for example.

```java
   public enum E
   {
   
      /** This is documentation for A. */A,
      /** This is documentation for B. */B,
      ;
      
   }
```

[image: An image of the JavaDoc that was generated for the code immediately above this image.]

But that is as far as Java lets you take it. Anything internal to the enum is considered an anonymous-instance-specific attribute, and thus, does not get any JavaDoc.

---

If you find yourself in a situation where you need that granular level documentation, why not make a sealed hierarchy? Something like this achieves similar functionality to `enum`'s, just not including all of the powerful features that enum's tend to have out of the box (`EnumSet`, `EnumMap`, `Enum::values`, etc.).

Here is an example of a sealed hierarchy that has some of the features that an `enum` would.

```java
   public sealed class E
   {
   
      /** E's implementation of m. */
      void m() {}
   
   }
   
   public final class A extends E
   {
   
      /** A's implementation of m. */
      void m() {}
   
   }
   
   public final class B extends E
   {
   
      @Override
      void m() {}
   
   }
```

And here is the JavaDoc that is generated from the following class.

[image: JavaDoc for the sealed type E]

[image: JavaDoc for the permitted subclass A]

[image: JavaDoc for the permitted subclass B]

Now we see that `A::m` has it's own JavaDoc.

And if you want to limit the instances that can be created, you can just use the singleton design pattern, while making `E` an `abstract class`. Here is what that might look like.

```java
   public abstract static sealed class E
   {
   
      /** E's implementation of m. */
      abstract void m();
   
   }
   
   public static final class A extends E
   {
   
      public static final A SINGLETON = new A();
   
      private A(){}
      
      /** A's implementation of m. */
      void m() {}
   
   }
   
   public static final class B extends E
   {
   
      public static final B SINGLETON = new B();
   
      private B(){}
      
      @Override
      void m() {}
   
   }
```

And just like that, you have recreated (only the most basic features of) an enum. You can add an `::ordinal` or `::values` method if you like, amongst other things. But that's probably as far as you can go.